# Python inputs from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, python-import

I have a python file(file1.py) where i have written a script. Now, my friend asked me to keep the inputs in another python file(file2.py) and import the file in file1.py so that its becomes easy to modify the inputs if we keep it seperate file. So i created file2.py, copied the inputs there and saved it. Then i wrote the following line in file1.py: `from file2 import *` but its throwing error:

> TASK [Run the python script]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [automation_server]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg":
>   "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to
>   10.242.174.192 closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to 10.242.174.192 closed."], "stdout": "/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 19: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such
>   file or directory\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   \"/home/bgnanasekaran/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1591957555.760499-407
>   182191177023663/download_RI_build.py\", line 8, in \r\n
>   from file2 import
>   *\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 19: warning: setlocale:
>   LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory",
>   "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File
>   \"/home/bgnanasekaran/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1591957555.760499-407
>   182191177023663/download_RI_build.py\", line 8, in ", "
>   from file2 import *", "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'"]}

Note: I'll give some example of inputs in file2.py -

```
name="Suresh"
college="VIT"
```

Also note: I wrote all these python scripts to make it run with ansible playbook. This script is a part of play in my ansible playbook.

Please help me do this. I want a python file where i can store my python script inputs and use the same file in python script. This is not so related to ansible but more related to python.

Answer (score 0):

`import` is for python files only.

If you want to read content of a file you need to `open` it.

```
with open('filename', 'r') as handler:
    print(handler.readlines())
```

Is a minimal example

You could also try to use environment varibales, which is a much more common practice when dealing with deployment strategies

```
import os

VARIABLE = os.getenv('VARIBALE', 'default_value')
```

Then you run the script with:

```
VARIABLE=this ./pythonscript.py
```

Or export the variable into the environment in another way

Comment: But, I dont understand why this happens? I ran the script alone(without ansible), the ```from file2 import *``` worked but the same thing fails in ansible play?

Comment: It says it dosen't find the file. Ansible runs in a different location I guess.

Comment: yeah but it runs on my local machine and the play is written for remote server but if it executes the script present in local machine then the importing should also work right?

Comment: The remote server dosen't have the file. If you can't package them together, maybe you should try using environment variables. It's more common for deployment.

Comment: Yeah that's what i am saying. The remote server doesnt have the python script too but still its able perform the operations mentioned in it then why cant it import another python file then?

Answer (score 0):

you need a configuration file this [post](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/#:~:text=Python%20Configuration%20File,to%20avoid%20uploading%20it%20accidentally) might help you or you can create a class and all required variable as a class variable and import the class into your script.

Comment: But, I dont understand why this happens? I ran the script alone(without ansible), the ```from file2 import *``` worked but the same thing fails in ansible play?